# All possibilities between 2 Strings recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to make a recursive method what will return an array of a String with all the possibilities of two Strings.

Comment: @Raedwald some guidance on how to do this without a loop and only recursion.

Comment: *What* kind of guidance. We are not here to write your homework for you.

Comment: @KevinS you should pass prefix in recursion method invocation. Like `combine(n - 1, prefix + "aa")` and `combine(n - 1, prefix + "bb")`

Comment: @Raedwald some sort of pseudocode, maybe. But of course, I have to do it myself.

Comment: @Natalia thank you. But could you collaborate a little more with what you mean?

Comment: @KevinS the code should like `combine (n, prefix){ if n==0 return preifx else return combine(n-1, preifx + "aa") + comnine(n-1, prefix+"bb")`

Answer (score 1):

If you must use recursion then the simplest solution might be to have a second recursive method to replace the iteration:

```
private List<String> combine(final int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return Arrays.asList("");
    } else {
        return addStrings(combine(n - 1));
    }
}

private List<String> addStrings(List<String> current) {
    if (current.isEmpty()) {
        return new LinkedList<>();
    } else {
        List<String> result = addStrings(current.subList(1, current.size()));
        result.add("AA" + current.get(0));
        result.add("BB" + current.get(0));
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `addStrings` method performs the same function as your iteration. I've replaced the arrays with lists to make it a bit simpler but you can convert back to arrays easily.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I wasn't looking for answers, but for some pseudocode.

Comment: @KevinS what? This is _too much_ of an answer for you? I am not sure you understand what this site is here for.

Comment: @KevinS ok understood. Note that your comment requesting pseudocode was added after I submitted this answer. It's worth making it clear in the question what sort of help you are after. Most SO answers involve posting code so if that's not what you're after you need to be clear on that in your question. Even a note in the question that this was homework would have been useful.